# English-Esperanto false friends

Tags: word-choice

Where is there a list of false friends words that a beginner who's learning Esperanto from English must be aware of?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There's a rather good list of false friends on Wikibooks: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Esperanto/Appendix/False_friends#English

There are quite many, but looking through them might be a good idea, even for a beginner.

Answer (score 5):

David Jordan, in his book *Being Colloquial in Esperanto* (readable online), has written a list of "[Potentially Troublesome Words](http://pages.ucsd.edu/~dkjordan/eo/colloq/colloq190.html)", which includes false cognates with English, as well as Esperanto words that look similar to each other. And many entries include example sentences to help clarify further.

Answer (score 4):

I know about two:

- *aktuale* = *currently*, and not *actually* (See [*aktuala* in PIV](http://vortaro.net/#aktuala))
- *kontroli* = *check*, and not *control* (See [*kontroli* in PIV](http://vortaro.net/#kontroli))